# How can I send an email in Delphi without having to include external DLL files with my executable?

Tags: email, delphi, dll, indy

Our application needs to be able to send an email, preferably using SSL/TLS. We've been able to get this working successfully in the Delphi Tokyo/Rio using Indy components such as TIdSMTP.

However, this required us to include two DLL files in our project to support OpenSSL. Currently, our application requires nothing other than the EXE, which we value for easy deployment.

Is there a way to package the OpenSSL library somehow within our executable? Or is there another method to send emails within Delphi that does not require any DLLs?

Comment: You can embed the DLLs in your EXE's resources and extract them at runtime  before Indy loads them. Or you could try tweaking Indy's `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_static` unit for non-iOS platforms. However, Indy does not *require* OpenSSL, it is merely the default SSL/TLS library supported "out of the box". You can use any SSL/TLS library you want, you just need a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived class to wrap it. You can write your own, or you can find a 3rd party one. Eldos SecureBlackbox has an IOHandler for Indy. And I know there are wrappers for SChannel and LibTLS floating around.

Comment: But really, it is not that hard to just deploy 2 DLLs with your EXE, especially if you use an installer package (plenty to choose from), or even just a simple `.zip`/`.7z` file, if you really need a single-file deployment.

Comment: Deploy the DLLs. It's far cleaner.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've been specifically tasked with finding a solution to email without DLLs, so I want to explore all the options before coming back and saying it's not worth it. I did find a nice wrapper for SChannel. Looking into SChannel, is it something that our end users would have to manually configure or install on their end for our program to use it or does it just come pre-installed with Windows? Our product is Windows only, so we don't need to worry about other environments.

Comment: @dallin SChannel is built in to Windows.